# contact form fails wordpress html js, php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I downloaded a wordpress template (http://themes.tvda.eu/demos/identiq/) but I must've screwed up the contact form, not sure how. Could anyone enlighten me please?

It's also on https://github.com/fileradar/fileradar.github.io if easier.

Many thanks

```
    <!-- Start Contact Page -->
    <section id="contact" class="page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <hr class="feedbackline">
                    <div class="result">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Start Form -->
            <form class="well">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6 pull-left">
                        <label>Your name</label>
                        <input class="span6" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6 pull-right">
                        <label>Your e-mail</label>
                        <input class="span6" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12 textarea-margin">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea class="span12" rows="8" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="web-icon">8</i>Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- End Form -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Contact Page -->
```

Then the js file is:

```
$(function()
  {
  $("#contact form").submit(function()
                            {
    var form = $(this);
    var str = form.serialize();
    $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(msg)
        {
          $("#contact .result .alert").remove();
          msg = JSON.parse(msg);

          if(msg.status == 'OK')
          {
            $('#contact .result').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div');
          }
          else if(msg.text)
          {
            $.each(msg.text, function(i, elem){
              $('#contact .result').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + elem + '</div');
            })
          }
          else
          {
            $('#contact .result').append('<div class="alert alert-error">Error</div');
          }
        }
      })
    return false;
  })
})
```

and the two php's are:

```
<?php
    function ValidateEmail($email)
    {
        /*
        (Name) Letters, Numbers, Dots, Hyphens and Underscores
        (@ sign)
        (Domain) (with possible subdomain(s) ).
        Contains only letters, numbers, dots and hyphens (up to 255 characters)
        (. sign)
        (Extension) Letters only (up to 10 (can be increased in the future) characters)
        */

        $regex = '/([a-z0-9_.-]+)'. # name
        '@'. # at
        '([a-z0-9.-]+){1,255}'. # domain & possibly subdomains
        '.'. # period
        "([a-z]+){2,10}/i"; # domain extension 

        if($email == '') {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $eregi = preg_replace($regex, '', $email);
        }

        return empty($eregi) ? true : false;
    }
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    include 'contact_config.php';
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
    if($post)
    {
        include 'functions.php';

        $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
        $error = array();
        // Check name
        if(!$name)
        {
            $error[] = 'Please enter your name.';
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$email)
        {
            $error[] = 'Please enter an e-mail address.';
        }

        if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
        {
            $error[] = 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.';
        }

        // Check message (length)
        if(!$message || strlen($message) < 15)
        {
            $error[] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
        }

        if(!$error)
        {
            $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
                "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n" 
                ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n" 
                ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

            mail($to, $message, $headers);

            if($mail)
            {
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK'));
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'text' => array('Error')));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'text' => $error));
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How is the form submission not working? Is it returning an error or something?

Comment: It simply returns to top of the page, or sometimes, does simply nothing when button pressed.

Comment: you have messed up `#contact form` it should be on the form tag not on the container div.

Comment: @David if its outside the container the shaping is lost and JS still does not work.